# Transpiled code gives TypeError:is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I have JS module which will be used inside react project (CRA).

`index.js` looks like,

```
export { EvtScoket } from './socket';
```

`socket.js` looks like

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

export default class EvtSocket {
  constructor(socketURL) {
    this.socket = openSocket(socketURL);
  }
  joinAsParticipant = () => {
    this.socket.emit('participantJoin', 'session');
  };

  joinAsSpeaker = () => {
    this.socket.emit('speakerJoin', 'lobby');
  };

  subscribeToInitialQuesitons = (cb) => {
    this.socket.on('initialQuestions', (questions) => {
      cb(null, questions);
    });
  };

  subscribeToQuestion = (cb) => {
    this.socket.on('newQuestionGot', (question) => cb(null, question));
  };

  sendQuestion = (question) => {
    this.socket.emit('newQuestionOn', question);
  };
}
```

`babelrc` is like

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        // "targets": {
        //   "esmodules": true
        // },
        "modules": "commonjs"
      }
    ]
    // "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-export-extensions",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
      {
        "allowTopLevelThis": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

When I transpiled this code and used it React App it gives

`TypeError: eventtalk_core___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.EvtSocket is not a constructor`

It's imported and used like

```
import { EvtSocket } from 'evt-core';

...
 constructor(){
   ...
   this.socket = new EvtSocket('xxx');
 }
```

The initial error was with classProperties that's why I need to setup babel.

If I `console.log(EvtScoket)` it output `undefined`

When I import the socket file directly as `evt-core/lib/socket` it works seems something wrong with export in index.js

Comment: You've specified babel to use `commonjs` for your modules, however, you're using ES6 module import/export syntax? Why not console log `EvtSocket` to see what it actually looks like.

Comment: @tombraider it says `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few reasons here, but it looks like you have a typo in your export:

```
export { EvtScoket } from './socket'; // typo in "Socket", EvtScoket/EvtSocket

import { EvtSocket } from 'evt-core'; // importing a named export that does not exist
```

Fix that typo and see if things start working again. A quick test would be to just import the incorrectly typed module, e.g.

```
import { EvtScoket } from 'evt-core';
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `socket.js` file, you export your class as a `default` export.

This means you have to import it like this:

```js
import EvtSocket from './socket.js`
```

You can find more information about imports from [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults)

Comment: Whilst this is correct, we can assume that the author is importing the file from the `index.js` file that he has listed in his question. In that index file, he is using a named export rather than a default.